# PL/SQL : Handling exception in Case Statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having trouble handling exception in Case statment , for exmaple

```
Case when someiput is null then

     select something from sometable where somecondition=somevalue
      Exception 
         when NO_DATA_FOUND then
          someinput:=somevalue
        end;
      end case ;
```

Erro i get is Encountere Exception when expeting  case begin declare

So anyone can you please let me know how to handle this.THis is happening is oracle 11g 
Could easily reproducible in other version as well

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about the case statement in QUERY or PLSQL?. In PLSQL you can write Begin, Exception and End block within the case statement. Like,

```
Case
when someiput is null then

  Begin
    select something into val
      from sometable
     where somecondition = somevalue; 

  Exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then 
    someinput :=   somevalue;
  end;
end case;
```

I hope it help!

Comment: @ashwin - this is the answer. Your proc was missing the `BEGIN` to go with the `EXCEPTION`.